# Javascript unescape doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have a simple string which is

```
Company&#39;s
```

Now I have some javascript which is ran when a form is submitted

```
var jsCompanyName = '@Model.Name';
var unescapedCompanyName = unescape(jsCompanyName);
$('.selector-input').val(unescapedCompanyName);
$('.selector-input-id').val('@Model.Id');
```

Going thought with a debugger, my var unescapedCompanyName is still "Company&#39;s" even after the unescape function, does anyone have any idea on why this isn't removing `&#39;` and replacing it with a '

Comment: What about `jsCompanyName = '@Html.Raw(Model.Name)'` ?

Comment: That doesn't seem work either

Comment: [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) 1) is deprecated 2) doesn't do what you think it would do

Comment: `Html.Raw` should not print any code on the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily with `JQUERY` if you really need to:

```
function htmlDecode(value) {
    return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}

var str = 'Company&#39;s';
console.log(htmlDecode(str)); // Company's
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/pb5dLvrz/).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but why using jQuery for that simple task ?

Comment: Cross browser feature. Easy to read. If you don't use JQUERY in your site then use @Pointy's solution, but if you do then why not?

Comment: That works perfectly mate, I am using JQuery so this is the better answer for me but I have upvoted both answers :)

Answer (score 6):

The `unescape()` function has nothing to do with HTML syntax. It's for handling escapes in URL syntax, which is a completely different thing. (It's also deprecated even for its intended purpose.)

There's no built-in function to deal with HTML escapes. However, code running in a web browser can do something like this:

```
function html_unescape(s) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = s;
  return div.textContent || div.innerText; // IE is different
}
```

Comment: +1 because somebody has to upvote the correct answer

Comment: @dystroy I looked for a duplicate too; I found a couple of vaguely-related old questions but nothing really close.

Comment: It's not easy to find, yes, but it looks like Quantas found it